# Set line height in the <br> tag - JSX element

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, line-height

I know the standard HTML for how to set line-height `<br style="line-height: 200%;">` in the `<br>` tag, but in the react JSX elements, I am not sure how to set it.
Below is the code I've tried, but it doesn't increase the height. I want actual results that can increase the height of the element.

```
<>
<br style={{lineHeight: 60}} />
</>
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: try ```<br style={{ lineHeight: "60%"}} />``` usually styles in JSX follow this pattern ```attribute:"value"```

Comment: The code you entered works fine for me. Is the line height style shown in the dev tools?

Comment: @nima I tried your method also doesn't work

Comment: @FattSky It may be because of using nesting Tags. If you want to change lineHeight, you must change the style of the parent Tag.
example: ```<div style={{ lineHeight: 60}} >
<br />
<div/>```